# Install Bluetooth SPP on Android tablet

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluez, spp

I am unable to discover my Bluetooth printer from my Android JellyBean tablet. But both the devices are discoverable from my macbook. The bluetooth printer spec says that it uses SPP (Serial Port Profile) to communicate. sdptool output is below

```
shell@android:/ # sdptool browse local
Browsing FF:FF:FF:00:00:00 ...
Service RecHandle: 0x10000
Service Class ID List:
  "PnP Information" (0x1200)
Profile Descriptor List:
  "PnP Information" (0x1200)
    Version: 0x0102

Service Name: Audio Source
Service RecHandle: 0x10001
Service Class ID List:
  "Audio Source" (0x110a)
Protocol Descriptor List:
  "L2CAP" (0x0100)
    PSM: 25
  "AVDTP" (0x0019)
    uint16: 0x102
Profile Descriptor List:
  "Advanced Audio" (0x110d)
    Version: 0x0102

Service Name: AVRCP TG
Service RecHandle: 0x10002
Service Class ID List:
  "AV Remote Target" (0x110c)
Protocol Descriptor List:
  "L2CAP" (0x0100)
    PSM: 23
  "AVCTP" (0x0017)
    uint16: 0x103
Profile Descriptor List:
  "AV Remote" (0x110e)
    Version: 0x0100

Service Name: Voice Gateway
Service RecHandle: 0x10003
Service Class ID List:
  "Headset Audio Gateway" (0x1112)
  "Generic Audio" (0x1203)
Protocol Descriptor List:
  "L2CAP" (0x0100)
  "RFCOMM" (0x0003)
    Channel: 11
Profile Descriptor List:
  "Headset" (0x1108)
    Version: 0x0100

Service Name: OBEX Object Push
Service RecHandle: 0x10004
Service Class ID List:
  "OBEX Object Push" (0x1105)
Protocol Descriptor List:
  "L2CAP" (0x0100)
  "RFCOMM" (0x0003)
    Channel: 12
  "OBEX" (0x0008)
Profile Descriptor List:
  "OBEX Object Push" (0x1105)
    Version: 0x0100

Service Name: Network service
Service Description: Network service
Service RecHandle: 0x10005
Service Class ID List:
  "Network Access Point" (0x1116)
Protocol Descriptor List:
  "L2CAP" (0x0100)
    PSM: 15
  "BNEP" (0x000f)
    Version: 0x0100
    SEQ16: 800 806
Language Base Attr List:
  code_ISO639: 0x656e
  encoding:    0x6a
  base_offset: 0x100
Profile Descriptor List:
  "Network Access Point" (0x1116)
    Version: 0x0100
```

Tried to add SP

```
shell@android:/ # sdptool add SP
Serial Port service registered
```

After adding SP, browse listing using sdptool shows SP service

```
Service Name: Serial Port
Service Description: COM Port
Service Provider: BlueZ
Service RecHandle: 0x10006
Service Class ID List:
  "Serial Port" (0x1101)
Protocol Descriptor List:
  "L2CAP" (0x0100)
  "RFCOMM" (0x0003)
    Channel: 1
Language Base Attr List:
  code_ISO639: 0x656e
  encoding:    0x6a
  base_offset: 0x100
Profile Descriptor List:
  "Serial Port" (0x1101)
    Version: 0x0100
```

I tried discovery with this setup and it still doesnt find the bluetooth printer.

I am not sure if SP was installed on the bluez stack on my Android as i couldn't find hcitool or rfcomm executables.

here is the listing on my /etc/bluetooth folder

```
shell@android:/ # ls /etc/bluetooth/                                           
BCM40183B2_26M.hcd
audio.conf
auto_pairing.conf
blacklist.conf
bt_addr.conf
input.conf
main.conf
network.conf
```

Comment: adding sdp record in local device makes ur device capable of that service, can you execute "sdptool browse"  and check the services which your printer supports?

Comment: i have a mac and unable to run command line tools to query the service. Will go to a friends place to run them and get back.